# How to set (global) variables under scheduled repeating task?

Tags: python, count, global-variables, schedule

I am testing a simple python script to collect images. Set a fixed timing to run the script every day, but I want to keep a count continuously increasing.

```
schedule.every().day.at(time1).do(job)
```

I realized that if I do not do that, new images will overwrite the old images. I want to find a way to properly count/name the newly downloaded images in the next day. Can anyone help?

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Maybe others do, but I don't. Would you like to name the created image with a specific time-format, such that the file is not overwritten? For this, you need to show the code that saves the image.

Comment: @nostradamus yeah true. you reminded me thx. I used to only name it as of sequence like 1.jpg, 2.jpg, and the next round will overwrite the images. I think now I can either name the image not using the number, or first count how many images in the folder and then keep naming the new images fowling with the count number

Comment: Sure, that will do. Or you import `time` and name it with the actual date and time when the image was taken / saved.